# the npm start shows error making local host won't run

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal, hosting, web-development-server

I am learning react. When i try to run npm start it shows the error as
PS C:\Users\AARYAE\OneDrive\Desktop\tr> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\AARYAE\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-15T07_13_38_065Z-debug-0.log

I've tried changing the package.json and also tried removing cache it doesn't work still. my node.js version is uptodate and i also tried npm run dev it didn't work here are some screenshots.
[This image is of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlcMx.png) 
[This is the package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB0WA.png)

Answer (score 0):

To run a custom script with npm, you must put `npm run ***` before the script.
So your script should be:

```bash
npm run start
```

When you run `npm start`. Npm will search in its built-in scripts like `install`, `star`, `stars`, `publish`, etc... It can't find a script named `start`

Comment: i tried this but didn't workout it show the same error

Comment: Make sure your command is as level as the `package.json`
means: open if the package.json in a nesting folder of the `tr` folder, navigate to it first, `cd ....`